# Ansible flask tutorial unable to install

Tags: python, flask, ansible

I'm following this tutorial:
http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html

I installed an Ubuntu image on a EC2 and trying to run playbook, I get the following error:

> TASK: [install common packages needed for python application development] *****
>       failed: [54.173.67.23] => (item=libpq-dev,libmysqlclient-dev,libxml2-dev,libjpeg62,libjpeg62-dev,libfreetype6,libfreetype6-dev,zlib1g-dev,mysql-client,python-dev,python-setuptools,python-imaging,python-mysqldb,python-psycopg2,git-core,nginx) => {"failed": true, "item": "libpq-dev,libmysqlclient-dev,libxml2-dev,libjpeg62,libjpeg62-dev,libfreetype6,libfreetype6-dev,zlib1g-dev,mysql-client,python-dev,python-setuptools,python-imaging,python-mysqldb,python-psycopg2,git-core,nginx"}
>       msg: No package matching '$item' is available
>       FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Not sure what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you referenced is out of date. The syntax the Ansible playbooks use is now invalid. Try this instead

```
- name: Install python packages
  connection: local
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks: 
  - name: add nginx ppa
    apt_repository: 
      repo: "ppa:nginx/stable"

  - name: install common packages needed for python application development
    apt: 
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - libpq-dev
      - libmysqlclient-dev
      - libxml2-dev
      - libjpeg62
      - libjpeg62-dev
      - libfreetype6
      - libfreetype6-dev
      - zlib1g-dev
      - mysql-client
      - python-dev
      - python-setuptools
      - python-imaging
      - python-mysqldb
      - python-psycopg2
      - git-core
      - nginx

  - name: install pip
    easy_install: 
      name: pip

  - name: install various libraries with pip
    pip: 
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - virtualenv
      - supervisor
      - uwsgi
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with this:
ERROR: apt_repository is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Comment: Make sure the indentation is correct. It should be even with `name` on the line above. `apt_repository` is a valid module so that should be fine.

Comment: You need to set up the playbook also.. updated the example.

Comment: but I was running via the tutorial:
ansible-playbook devops/setup_server.yml -i devops/hosts
the host is specified in devops/hosts and it's a ec2 box running Ubuntu. I cannot use localhost since I'm on Mac.

Comment: ahh figured it out, I needed to specify the servername specified in devops/hosts